# How do I access navigation properties through XAML-based databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm attempting to learn WPF and MVVM and struggling with some databinding at the moment.  I have a ComboBox that contains an observable collection of Projects, and a TextBox which is bound to the SelectedItem of the ComboBox and displays an EmployeeID value.  I want to instead display the employee name that corresponds to the EmployeeID value, via a navigation property if possible, but not sure how to modify the XAML to allow for that.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID;
    public string ProjectName;
    public int EmployeeID;
    public Employee Emp;
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID;
    public string EmployeeName;        
}
```

MainView XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxProjects" Width="75" Height="20" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"                      
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedProject}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName" />

<TextBox x:Name="tbxEmployee" Height ="20" Width="100" BorderThickness="1"
         Text="{Binding Path=SelectedProject.EmployeeID}"/>
```

MainViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Project> _projects;
private Project _selectedProject;

public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
{
    get { { return _projects; } }                                        
}

public Project SelectedProject
{
    get { return _selectedProject; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedProject != value)
        {
            _selectedProject = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ObservableCollection properties should be read only.  And if you're a MVVM noob get an application called Snoop. It's invaluable.  Now, why doesn't your Project class have a property of type Employee?  That's the way to do it.  Otherwise, get the employee in the setter for SelectedProject.

Comment: That is good to know (read only), and I will definitely check out Snoop as suggested, thanks.  This code is for example only, I'm using EF and the navigation properties are included with the entities.  In the ViewModel I can navigate to the Employee entity from the Project entity, but not sure how to do that with binding in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just bind to `Path=SelectedProject.Emp.EmployeetName` instead?

Comment: Yes, just like that. I was missing the "Path=".  Time for my nap.  Thanks.